# Python Heads Or Tails Program assistance

Tags: python, random

I am trying to make a *Heads Or Tails* program in Python. I am a newbie and I have just got into Python. What I try to achieve is to have the program pick either *Heads* or *Tails* without me knowing it (Yes, `import random`, etc.) and I would like to have a single try when guessing. This is what I have achieved so far, yet it is not very close to what i am looking for. Any thoughts? I have tried implementing the different random arguments I found on a Python website but they don't work (such as `randint` for integers)... Thanks!

```
print """
Welcome to our game. This is a heads or tails game and you will be the one who gets to pick a possible answer. Lets begin!
"""

print "~-~-~-~-" * 10

theirGuess = raw_input("Whats your guess? :   ")
ourAnswer = "Heads"   # For Debugging purposes to check if the program works
notCorrectAnswer = "Tails"  # To eliminate the possibility of not being either tails or heads in case of mistaken answer 


if theirGuess == ourAnswer:
      print "You got it!"
elif theirGuess != notCorrectAnswer and ourAnswer:
    print "You didnt get it! Try entering either Tails or Heads!"
else:
    print "You didnt get it! Try again next time!"
```

Comment: `elif theirGuess != notCorrectAnswer and ourAnswer:` should be `elif theirGuess != notCorrectAnswer`. I assume you meant `elif theirGuess != ourAnswer and theirGuess != notCorrectAnswer`, but you've already established that `theirGuess != ourAnswer` by making it to the `elif` clause.

Comment: What i tried to write is, if the "player" enters something like "Tais" etc, with a mistake, the program will tell him that theres a mistake in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should try:

```
import random
ch = random.choice(["Heads","Tails"])
```

which will put into the variable `ch` either "Heads" or "Tails". Try to do something from that.

Comment: That worked like a charm. However, i wanted to keep looping through the program. In few words, i would like the players to keep playing the game until they exit themselves without having to launch the "application" again. This is my approach. Doesnt work. How could i change it? Sorry for the long questions :/

Comment: def second():
restart = raw_input("Would you like to restart this program and give it another try?")

y = "yes"
n = "no"

if restart == y:
     main()
elif restart == n:
   sys.exit(0)

Comment: You can also just put the whole thing into a `while` loop, with an additional `raw_input()` input.

Comment: Thing is, it doesnt work. Is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

To make the whole thing continue until exited by user, and including @Baruchel's answer:

```
import random
print """
Welcome to our game. This is a heads or tails game and you will be the one who gets to pick a possible answer. Lets begin!
"""
cont = 1 #To force the game to run for one round without user input
while(cont == 1): #cont is used to take user choice, whether to run it again or not
    print "~-~-~-~-" * 10


    theirGuess = raw_input("Whats your guess? :   ")
    ourAnswer = random.choice(["Heads","Tails"])
    if ourAnswer == "Heads":
        notCorrectAnswer = "Tails"
    else:
        notCorrectAnswer = "Heads"


    if theirGuess == ourAnswer:
        print "You got it!"
    elif theirGuess != notCorrectAnswer and ourAnswer:
        print "You didnt get it! Try entering either Tails or Heads!"
    else:
        print "You didnt get it! Try again next time!"

    cont = input("Do you want to continue? Press 1 if yes, press 0 if no.: ") #Take user choice on whether to run it again or not
    while (cont != 0 and cont != 1): # If user puts in a different number (neither 1 or 0), make them enter until they put a right choice
        cont = input("Please try again. Press 1 if yes, press 0 if no.: ")
```

Comment: That summed it up. Didnt quite get why you set cont to 1 but then set it to the input and then to the other input, but it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I set `cont` to 1 to run the loop for the first time (ie., to play the first round of the game). Then it is up to the user to choose whether to play again or not. But in case they accidentally enter something other than 1 or 0, I have them enter a number again. Ideally that part should be in a loop so that every time the user puts a wrong number (ie., not 0 or 1), s/he is prompted.